# Copy nginx cache between two servers

Tags: nginx, cache, cluster, replication, copy

I have a nginx caching server with at least 2tb of cache files at any moment, i need to migrate this server to another hosting provider but none of my clients can handle that traffic without cache.

At my first try, just copying the cache object to another instance with the same configuration and permissions, it fails with MISS.
I changed the permissions, groups and every time it fails and create a new cache file.

It's possible to copy my cache files and get HIT in the first access?

Comment: Do you use the exact same version of nginx in both environments and/or have the same value set for `proxy_cache_key`  (where the default might change between versions)? i guess there is a mismatch in the calculated hash based on some config values that might implicitly have changed between versions.

Comment: A few "Ifs" coming up..... If the current server is virtual and if the cache is sitting on its own virtual disk. You could move the whole disk and mount it on the new server

Comment: Can't you warm the cache up at the new location using some cache warming tool? Or send only 1% of the traffic there for a while. This is good practice anyway.